# jQuery calendar with popup form

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jQuery plugin exactly like on this page:
http://www.specsavers.co.uk/stores/kingsbury/your-appointment/

Comment: There's probably not a single plugin-based solution to this; you'll have to take one of the offerings you find in the answer(s) below and customize it to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout below links choose whats best suits you.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-calendar-date-pickers.html

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-calendar-plugins/

Comment: I post question after research and such useless urls i have visited. I think u did not checked 
http://www.specsavers.co.uk/stores/kingsbury/your-appointment/

Comment: is this useless? R u ok? You can't even open a popup form(which is actually a div/table or some view) while clicking on specific calendar's date?

Comment: @MuhammadSajid You know, it's often considered bad form to put down the people who are trying to help you. Especially when your question is better suited to Google than to StackOverflow anyway.